# 'usr/bin' is not included in the path environment

Tags: linux, bash, unix, terminal

Whenever I start a new terminal and try to run a command, I get this error.
I have found out that it can be solved with export PATH=/usr/bin:/bin, but it has to be done for each terminal I open. In the etc/environment file, the path is correct, so hence I do not understand what is wrong.(But this error appeared after I added some lines to bashrc and paths to have some shortcuts for ruby, rails , git ; ( was following a course on Coursera )).
How can this be fixed?

Comment: This is only a temporary fix, but you could just put the line 'export PATH=/usr/bin:/bin' in your ~/.bashrc

Comment: There's something wrong with what you added to your .bashrc, but without seeing it there's no way for us to tell what it is.

Comment: Is the error message in the title ("`'usr/bin' is not included in the path environment`") accurate?  It looks like it is missing the leading `/` of `/usr/bin`.  Have you echoed `$PATH`?  Does it look plausible?  You need to fix up your profile or other environment setting scripts to get the PATH right.

Comment: @GordonDavisson here are the exports in the .bashrc(after fi )
export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"
eval "$(rbenv init -)"
export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/plugins/ruby-build/bin:$PATH"
export PATH=/home/mircea/IDE/SublimeText3
export PATH=/usr/bin/git

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, the full error is : "Command 'x' is available in '/bin/afolder' The command could not be loaded becasuse '/bin' is nt included in the PATH environment variable"   where x a command given (eg ls)

Comment: If you have `export PATH=/usr/bin/git`, then obviously your `PATH` will only containt `/usr/bin/git`. Fix your `.bashrc`. And by the way, you don't need all these `export`.

Comment: I've solve this issue by following way : Check here... https://askubuntu.com/a/1318368/1185282

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What's happened here is you've clobbered your PATH variable. Your PATH is pretty important, whenever you enter a command your shell (usually bash), will check each of the directories specified in your PATH for a program of the same name.

Each directory specified in your path is separated by a colon `:`, and a minimal PATH variable usually looks something like `/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin`.

When you have the line `export PATH=/usr/bin/git` at the end of your `.bashrc` you are telling your shell that you only want to search `/usr/bin/git` for commands.

Instead, the line `export PATH="$PATH:/usr/bin/git"` will tell your shell to search all of the directories previously specified in your shell,  and then search `/usr/bin/git`.

Another thing to note is that your shell will search the directories in your PATH in the order they're specified, and use the first matching command found, so the order that directories are specified in the PATH can matter too.

Comment: It may also be worth noting that PATH. Contains directories but `/usr/bin/git` is probably an executable, not a directory.

Comment: I've solve this issue by following way : Check here... https://askubuntu.com/a/1318368/1185282